# Scrape HTTPS REST API from an Android app installed in computer

Tags: rest, ssl, https, fiddler, wireshark

We are building an Android App and we are worried about the REST API being scraped.

Would it be possible to detect the REST endpoints used for the app if somebody manages to install the app in a computer and uses a software like Wireshark to sniff the connection?

The connection is HTTPS

If possible, what is the way of preventing people from using these REST APIs on their own?

Answer (score 0):

> We are building an Android App ... if somebody manages to install the app in a computer

I.e., you're worried about either 1) a computer running Android or whatever Google's "Android+Chrome merge" thing is or 2) a computer running some software under which Android apps can run?

> and uses a software like Wireshark to sniff the connection? ... The connection is HTTPS

Sniffing an SSL/TLS connection gives you a bunch of encrypted data unless [you give Wireshark enough data to decrypt it, and it's a situation where it *can* decrypt it](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL#SSL_dissection_in_Wireshark).

However, a debugging proxy such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) might be able to catch the traffic and decrypt it in situations where Wireshark couldn't.

Comment: You are right, but how to prevent Charles proxy from sniffing